# Error using perl module Parallel::ForkManager

Tags: multithreading, perl

I am getting the following error message when I am using the perl module Parallel::ForkManager, and I can't figure out what's wrong in my code.

What's weird is that the program run fine for the first 70 bam files it is sending on the different threads and then it output me the error bellow.

Any help would be so appreciate.

Thanks a lot. :)

Here is the errors:

Cannot fork: Cannot allocate memory at /usr/local/perl-5.24.0/lib/site_perl/5.24.0/Parallel/ForkManager.pm line 52,  line 8260.

The storable module was unable to store the child's data structure to the temp file "/tmp/1341650.1.longjob.q/dZnCgF1MiR/Parallel-ForkManager-28852-28855.txt":  can't create /tmp/1341650.1.longjob.q/dZnCgF1MiR/Parallel-ForkManager-28852-28855.txt: No such file or directory at /usr/local/perl-5.24.0/lib/site_perl/5.24.0/Parallel/ForkManager.pm line 84.

Here is my code:

```
if ($threads == 1) {
    for my $id (0 .. $nbInputFiles) {
        $self->{$id}->{_currentFile} = $self->{inputFiles}[$id] ;
        $self->readBamInputFile($id) ;
        $self->correctMatrice($id) ;
        print STDERR "INFO $prog $datestring: $self->{$id}->{_currentFile} -> correcting matrice done !\n" ;
    }
}
else {
    my $pm = new Parallel::ForkManager($threads);
    $pm->set_waitpid_blocking_sleep(0);

    $pm->run_on_finish(sub {
        my ($pid, $exit, $id, $signal, $core, $data) = @_;

        $self->{$id}->{cov} = $data->{ret}->{$id}->{cov} ;
        $self->{$id}->{_currentSample} = $data->{ret}->{$id}->{_currentSample} ;
        $self->correctMatrice($id) ;
        print STDERR "INFO $prog $datestring: $data->{ret}->{$id}->{_currentFile} -> correcting matrice done !\n" ;

        $ret[$id] = delete $data->{ret};
        $err[$id] = delete $data->{err};
    });

    for my $id (0 .. $nbInputFiles) {
        $self->{$id}->{_currentFile} = $self->{inputFiles}[$id] ;
        $pm->start($id) and next;

        # here do the child
        # my $res = eval { $task[0]->($self) };
        my $res = eval { &readBamInputFile($self, $id) };
        $pm->finish(0, { ret => $self, err => $@ });
    }
    $pm->wait_all_children;
}
```

Comment: Okay, and does `/tmp/1341650.1.longjob.q/dZnCgF1MiR` exist when the error appears? (This directory will have a different name each time you run your program.)

Comment: Have you tried processing the errant file just by itself, i.e., outside this attempt at parallel processing?  It would certainly be plausible for Storable to have problems with the file it it were defective.

Comment: @James: `Storable` is used internally by `Parallel::ForkManager`. It is used to pass information back from the child threads to the parent.

Comment: Cross-posted at Biostars: https://www.biostars.org/p/323998/

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping it in array ref worked for me.

```
$pm->finish(0, [{x=>1}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the `/tmp` drive is getting full, or there's some permission issue, or some process is cleaning it up behind your back.

Try using another directory for the temporary file.

To do that, set the environment variable `TMPDIR`, or pass the name of the directory as a second argument to the constructor:

```
Parallel::ForkManager->new($max_process, $tmp_dir_qfn)
```

Comment: Your solution solved the problem of "storable module". But I am still getting the "Cannot fork" error message.

I check the ForkManager.pm module and it seams that $pid is not defined when the module launch the line "my $pid=fork();"

However, I can't figure out why $pid isn't define.

I wonder if the error is related to the way I code the program: the job a one file will be send to one slot. In my case I have ~300files, the first 70 are running smoothy and then I am getting this error...

Comment: `$!` is set to an error message when `fork` returns undef. Most likely, you're hitting the limit on the number of child processes your process can have at once. That might be configurable